# Error The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value when deploying my azure function resource

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I am attempting to deploy .NET Framework application with Azure function, i am working off an existing ARM json template which i converted to `.bicep` file. One of the resources is the below

```
resource resourceName_resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: resourceName
  location: resourceLocation
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
 }
  tags: {
    'hidden-related:${appServicePlan_ResourceId}': 'empty'
  }
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    reserved: false
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan_ResourceId
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    appServicePlan_name
    storage_name
  ]
}
```

However when i run the deployment i get the below error, now i am assuming the error is caused by the above configuration as thats the only resource with LinuxFxVersion. How do i correct this error ?

```
{
   "status":"Failed",
   "error":{
      "code":"DeploymentFailed",
      "message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
      "details":[
         {
            "code":"BadRequest",
            "message":"{\r\n  \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"Message\": \"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.\",\r\n  \"Target\": null,\r\n  \"Details\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"Message\": \"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"Code\": \"BadRequest\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"ErrorEntity\": {\r\n        \"ExtendedCode\": \"01007\",\r\n        \"MessageTemplate\": \"The parameter {0} has an invalid value.\",\r\n        \"Parameters\": [\r\n          \"LinuxFxVersion\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n        \"Message\": \"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Innererror\": null\r\n}"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check the bicep for deploying the `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` resource. I recall a similar error because I had left out the property setting `reserved: true`. Once I added that setting, then the deployment succeeded. If you already created the app service plan, you'll need to remove it and redeploy in order for the change to be accepted.

I ran the following and it worked.

```
param location string = 'East US'

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'apphostingplanname'
  location: location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    tier: 'Standard'
    name: 'S1'
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}

resource resourceName_resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'somewebapp72478340'
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
 }
  tags: {
    'hidden-related:${hostingPlan.id}': 'empty'
  }
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    reserved: false
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
    }
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]